# car package to qqplot in R - how to insert the scale of x and y axis

Tags: r, package

The answer is little specific, I am using this package called CAR for R to plot qqplot.

My question is - I am able to plot the graph but not to put the scale of the axis using - xlim or ylim.

Any ideas of how to get it  done

Additional info:

```
qqPlot {car}
Version:    2.0-22
Depends:    R (≥ 2.14.0), stats, graphics    
## Default S3 method:
    qqPlot(x, distribution="norm", ...,
        ylab=deparse(substitute(x)), xlab=paste(distribution, "quantiles"), 
        main=NULL, las=par("las"),
        envelope=.95,  
        col=palette()[1], col.lines=palette()[2], lwd=2, pch=1, cex=par("cex"), 
        line=c("quartiles", "robust", "none"),  
        labels = if(!is.null(names(x))) names(x) else seq(along=x),
        id.method = "y", 
        id.n =if(id.method[1]=="identify") Inf else 0,
        id.cex=1, id.col=palette()[1], grid=TRUE)



sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] car_2.0-22
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to be adjustable. If you need such a modification, I suggest you to switch to the basic functions `stats::qqnorm` and `stats::qqplot`. If you desire a more attractive plot, you can switch to `ggplot2`. Look at http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_qq.html