# x and y limits for qqplot using car package in R

Tags: r, plot, quantile

I generated  a qqplot using the car package in R but not able to adjust the x and y scale. The graph looks like this:

[image: normal qqplot]

I need to blow up the x and y axis to look at how close they are to the confidence intervals. Is there a way to solve this?
The qqPlot function in car package does not have arguments xlim and ylim
[Arguments of qqPlot in car package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np1XY.png)

Comment: Please include some sample code and data

Answer (score 0):

Edit: My mistake. I didn't read closely enough to see that you were using the car package. Adding example code in your question would be useful in the future.

Looks like the axes in car::qqPlot might not be adjustable. Per the suggestion in this answer ([car package to qqplot in R - how to insert the scale of x and y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348198/car-package-to-qqplot-in-r-how-to-insert-the-scale-of-x-and-y-axis)), try using the basic function (stats::qqplot) instead.

---

Try calling xlim and ylim in your qqplot function.

Here's an example using the sample data from the ?qqplot documentation:

```
## data
y <- rt(200, df = 5)

## plot will have x-axis from -4 to 6 and y-axis from -4 to 4
qqplot(y, rt(300, df = 5)) 

## plot will have x-axis from -4 to 2 and y-axis from -4 to 0
qqplot(y, rt(300, df = 5), 
       ylim = c(-4, 0), 
       xlim = c(-4, 2))
```